# SVG Raphaeljs Creating a grid of rectangles

Tags: html, svg, raphael

I want to create a user defined grid of rectangles using SVG Raphaeljs. The method I am using at the moment is close to what I want it to do but its clearly not right.

My code as of now :

**Creating the rectangles and trying to get them placed in an even grid of equal distance from each other**

```
function startup() {
var paper = Raphael(50, 50, 1500, 875);
for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {

        var offset = i; // Stores the number to remove from the next variable to keep an even distance between shapes
        var moveRight = (i + 20 - offset) * i; // new variable stores the amount to move the next rectangle along by adding 20 (distance in pixels
        // to move to the right) to the loop counter i and then subtracting the offset which is the variable i
        // before the + 20 was added and then multiplying it all by i again.
        var moveDown = (j + 35 - offset) * j;


        var c = paper.rect(moveRight, moveDown, 15, 20);

        c.attr("fill", "#f00");
        c.attr("stroke", "#fff");
    }
}
```

}

The above currently produces this wonky grid as a result of my poor coding.

[image: Attempt at the moment]

I need this to work in such a way that the user can enter the actual amount of rows and columns just by editing the values I put into the for loops and then using that number to change the distance each shape is placed,

As you can see I tried to do this by making a rough formula but I am now stuck, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, silly on my part. I've noticed a mistake and I've amended my code to the following:

```
function startup() {
    var paper = Raphael(50, 50, 1500, 875);
    for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {

            var offseti = i; // Stores the number to remove from the next variable to keep an even distance between shapes
            var moveRight = (i + 20 - offseti) * i; // new variable stores the amount to move the next rectangle along by adding 20 (distance in pixels
            // to move to the right) to the loop counter i and then subtracting the offset which is the variable i
            var offsetj = j; // before the + 20 was added and then multiplying it all by i again.
            var moveDown = (j + 25 - offsetj) * j;


            var c = paper.rect(moveRight, moveDown, 15, 20);

            c.attr("fill", "#f00");
            c.attr("stroke", "#fff");

        }
    }
}
```

[image]